# Testing a simple REST service with Jasmine (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service

After trying many samples I'm coming to end. I don't know what to do that the test is working..

I've tried the following to test:

```
//CrudService who is invoked in the Ctrl
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('CrudService', ['ResService',
        function (ResService) {
            var service = {
                getAllCompanies: getAllCompanies
            };

            return service;

            function getAllCompanies() {
                return ResService.company.query();
            }
...

//That's the nested service ResService

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('ResService', ['$resource', 'baseUrl',
        function ($resource, baseUrl) {
            return {

                company: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/company/:Id/:code', {
                    Id: '@Id',
                    code: '@code'
                }, {
                    'update': {
                        method: 'PUT'
                    }
                }),
...
```

Now, I want to test `CrudService.getAllCompanies()` whether it returned something.

The following code was an attempt:

```
describe('CrudService', function () {
  var httpBackend, mockCrudService, baseUrl;
  var mockData = {
     Id: 1,
     cname: 'Company World Inc.',
     shortcode: 'ABCD',
     maxValue: 3,
     GroupId: 1
  };

  beforeEach(function () {
     module('myApp');

     inject(function ($injector) {
       httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
       mockCrudService = $injector.get('CrudService');
       baseUrl = $injector.get('baseUrl');
     });
  });

  afterEach(function () {
       httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
       httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('test the service', inject(function (CrudService) {
       httpBackend.expectGET(baseUrl + '/api/company').respond(200, mockData);

       var result = mockCrudService.getAllCompanies(mockData);

       httpBackend.flush();

       expect(result.shortcode).toEqual(mockData.shortcode);
  }));
```

It doesn't work. I'm always getting the following Error messages:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET views/fonds.html
>   No more request

and

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest in
>   http://localhost:60694/js/angular.min.js (line 6)
>   expected

Comment: `view/fonds.html` is probably defines somewhere in your code. so have a look there and try to figure out why this part of the code is executed. Also the full stack trace would be helpful. For full support on the matter please provide a running plunker.

Comment: @Michael that's a view who will executed the Service..or better said in the Controller of this view. But is that kind of definition of tests the right way?

Comment: yeah it look like it tries to load the view, but that is not part of the test - isn't it. If you need more support please provide a running plunker.

Comment: @Michael ok I will do that and write you back.. Could you tell me what the second error means?

Comment: The second error means there was an error in the digest phase. You get better error messages if you use the normal angular.js instead of the minified version.

Comment: @Michael in the normal angular.js I'm getting this error: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest in http://localhost:60694/js/angular.js (line 68)`